# View product category tree (hierarchical view)

Tags: atg

I have products existing in multiple categories.

Example:

```
Category > Books > Hardcover Books > childCategory
Category > Promo Books > Sample > childCategory
```

Are there any helper classes that can be used to get the list of all the categories for a product?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not aware of any utility classes OOTB that will provide you with a full tree structure for a product. That said, it is not too difficult to build this up.

Given a `productId` and, assuming you know the 'root' `categoryId`, add the following methods to your extension of the `CatalogTools` class.

```
    private RqlStatement findParentCategoriesOfProductRQL;

    public RepositoryItem[] findParentCategoriesOfProduct(String productId, String rootCategoryId) throws RepositoryException {
        RepositoryView view = getCatalog().getView("category");
        RepositoryItem[] parentCategories = findParentCategoriesOfProductRQL.executeQuery(view, new Object[] {productId, rootCategoryId });
        if (parentCategories == null || parentCategories.length == 0) {
            return null;
        }
        return parentCategories;
    }

    public void setFindParentCategoriesOfProductRQL(RqlStatement findParentCategoriesOfProduct) {
        this.findParentCategoriesOfProductRQL = findParentCategoriesOfProduct;
    }

    public RqlStatement getFindParentCategoriesOfProductRQL() {
        return findParentCategoriesOfProductRQL;
    }
```

and add the following to your `CatalogTools.properties`

```
findParentCategoriesOfProductRQL=fixedChildProducts includes item (id = ?0) AND ancestorCategoryIds includes ?1
```

Comment: Thank you for the feedback. I will be looking into your code and CatalogTools.

Comment: Is there a way to do this with only the Catalog Tools? http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E52191_01/Platform.11-1/apidoc/atg/commerce/catalog/CatalogTools.html#getAncestors(atg.repository.RepositoryItem)

Comment: From the docs it looks like it might do what you want. Perhaps go down one class to the `CustomCatalogTools` class and see what it offers you there. Maybe more specific. http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E52191_01/Platform.11-1/apidoc/atg/commerce/catalog/custom/CustomCatalogTools.html#getAncestors(atg.repository.RepositoryItem)

Comment: getAncestors() only brings back the first item in that list of category trees.

Comment: The documentation suggests otherwise: `This method gets the parentCategory property of the repository item passed in, and gets the parentCategory's parentCategory and so forth until there is no more parent.`

Answer (score 1):

If you are using the CommerceReferenceStore (CRS) as the basis for your site, then your `/atg/commerce/catalog/CatalogTools` component uses the `StoreCatalogTools` class, which extends the `atg.commerce.catalog.custom.CustomCatalogTools` class. Otherwise, if your `CatalogTools` component does not use the `CustomCatalogTools` class, you will need to update it so that it does.

The following [method](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E52191_01/Platform.11-1/apidoc/atg/commerce/catalog/custom/CustomCatalogTools.html#getProductsCategories(atg.repository.RepositoryItem,%20atg.repository.Repository)) is available:

```
public java.util.Collection getProductsCategories(RepositoryItem pProduct,
                                         Repository pCatalogRepository)
                                           throws RepositoryException
```

You may call it using the default catalog like this:

```
getCatalogTools().getProductsCategories(productItem, getCatalog());
```